# Is there a way to Include / Render a variable in EJS?

Tags: node.js, express, ejs

Is there a way to have the contents of an include come from a variable instead of a from a file?

I need to get the contents of the include from a database instead of a file, I would like to do something like this:

Contents of example.ejs:

```html
<h1>Example EJS template<h1>
<p><%- include(data.includeCode) %><p>
```

Nodejs / Express with EJS code:

```js
let includeCode = `<% if (data.dSwitch === 1) { %> 1 detected <% } else { %> Something else <% } %>`

let ejsdata = {...{includeCode: includeCode}, ...{dSwitch: 1}};

res.render("example.ejs",{data:ejsdata});
```

What I would like to see is the following output:

```html
<h1>Example EJS template</h1>
<p> 1 detected </p>
```

I tried using <%- data.includeCode %> but that outputs as

```html
<h1>Example EJS template</h1>
<p> <% if (data.dSwitch === 1) { %> 1 detected <% } else { %> Something else <% } %> </p>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution is to call ejs.render from the ejs template:

Contents of example.ejs:

```html
<h1>Example EJS template<h1>
<p><%- ejs.render(data.includeCode,{data:data}) %><p>
```

NodeJS / Express with EJS code:

```js
import ejs from "ejs";
globalThis.ejs = ejs; // make sure ejs is available in the global context

let includeCode = `<% if (data.dSwitch === 1) { %> 1 detected <% } else { %> Something else <% } %>`

let ejsdata = {...{includeCode: includeCode}, ...{dSwitch: 1}};

res.render("example.ejs",{data:ejsdata});
```

Resulting Output:

```html
<h1>Example EJS template</h1>
<p> 1 detected </p>
```